# Kalman filter behaviour

Tags: python, kalman-filter

I have used the kalman filter implented here: https://gist.github.com/alexbw/1867612

I have a very basic understanding of it. this is the test code I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from Kalman import Kalman

n = 50    
d = 5

xf = np.zeros(n - d)
yf = np.zeros(n - d)

xp = np.zeros(d)
yp = np.zeros(d)

x = np.zeros(n)
y = np.zeros(n)

for i in range(n):

    if i==0:
        x[i] = 05
        y[i] = 20
        KLF = Kalman(6, 2)

    elif i< (n - d):
        xf[i], yf[i] = KLF.predict()  
        x[i] = x[i-1] + 1
        y[i] = y[i-1] + np.random.random() * 10
        NewPoint = np.r_[x[i], y[i]]
        KLF.update(NewPoint)
    else:
        x[i] = x[i-1] + 1
        y[i] = y[i-1] + np.random.random() * 10
        xp[n - i -1], yp[n - i -1] = KLF.predict()  
        NewPoint = np.r_[x[i] , yp[n - i -1]]
        KLF.update(NewPoint)

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x, y, 'ro') #original
plt.plot(xp, yp, 'go-') #predicted kalman
plt.plot(xf, yf, 'b') #kalman filter
plt.legend( ('Original', 'Prediction', 'Filtered') ) 
plt.show()
```

[image]

My question is, why does the kalman filtering starts at 0 if the data starts at x=5, y=20 ?
Is that some sort of standard behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current state of the Kalman instance is stored in the `x` attribute:

```
In [48]: KLF = Kalman(6, 2)

In [49]: KLF.x
Out[49]: 
matrix([[ 0.],
        [ 0.],
        [ 0.],
        [ 0.],
        [ 0.],
        [ 0.]])
```

The six components represent the position, velocity and acceleration. So by default the Kalman instance starts at `(0,0)` with zero velocity and acceleration.

After instantiating `KLF`, when `i=1`, the first modification to `xf` and `yf` is made by calling `KLF.predict`:

```
xf[i], yf[i] = KLF.predict()
```

There are two problems with this. First, `xf[0], yf[0]` is never updated, so it remains at `(0, 0)`. Hence the blue line starting at `(0, 0)`.

The second problem is that the current state of `KLF.x` is at `(0, 0)` by default, due to the way the Kalman class is defined.
If you want the `KLF` instance to begin with a position at `(5, 20)` then you'll need to modify `KLF.x` yourself.

Also bear in mind that the Kalman filter is meant to be updated with an *observation first* and then make a *prediction second*.
This is mentioned in the class docstring.

Now I don't quite understand the intent of your code so I'm not going to try to sort out how the `update`s should come before the `predict`s, but as far as setting the initial state is concerned, you could use this:

```
if i==0:
    x[i] = 5
    y[i] = 20
    KLF = Kalman(6, 2)
    KLF.x[:2] = np.matrix((x[0], y[0])).T
    xf[i], yf[i] = KLF.predict()
```

which yields

[image]

Comment: Great. How to calculate the R2 score in this case? Could you help me? please.